# зачем синтаксис распространения в начале методов и как это в данном случае работает?

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6

как он работает spread оператор тут ,зачем он в начале методов ,в курсе по vue обходятся без него ,зачем он тут понадобился?

```
export default {
            name: 'App',
            data() {
                return {
                    activeItemId: null,
                }
            },
            components: {
                ViewDataList,
                ViewDataItem
            },
            computed: {
                ...mapGetters(['loadStatus', 'dataItemInfo', 'currentItem', 'secondStep'])
            },
            methods: {
                ...mapActions(['loadDataItemInfo', 'moveBack']),
        
                async nextStep() {
                    this.loadDataItemInfo();
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: `spread` лучше не переводить :)

Comment: я в видео уроках не видел его использование, зачем он понадобился тут и как это работает?

Answer (score 1):

`mapGetters` и аналогичные функции возвращают *объект*. Чтобы встроить полученный объект и используется [`spread` оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals)

Например:

`mapActions` возвращает следующий объект

```
{
    'loadDataItemInfo': function(){...}, 
    'moveBack': function(){...}
}
```

Если вставлять результат без `spread` оператора вид объекта будет следующий

```
methods: {
    actions:     {
        'loadDataItemInfo': function(){...}, 
        'moveBack': function(){...}
    },

    async nextStep() {
        this.loadDataItemInfo();
    }
}
```

Для того, чтобы получить более плоскую структуру и используют `spread` оператор, встраивающий свойства одного объекта в другой

```
methods: {
    'loadDataItemInfo': function(){...}, 
    'moveBack': function(){...},
    async nextStep() {
        this.loadDataItemInfo();
    }
}
```